Can I use "Not at all." as a response to "Is it okay if I ~?"
Can I use "Not at all." instead of "Sure." as a response to "Is it okay if I bring my little brother?" What about "Would it be alright if I bring my little brother?" I've always thought that "Not at all." was only used to give permission in response to "Do you mind if I ~?" questions, and for all other questions, I’d use something like "Sure." or "Of course."

My teacher said that this conversation sounds natural: "A: Let’s get two student tickets. B: Oh, would it be alright if I bring my little brother? A: Not at all. But it says that you are not allowed to bring children under 8." In this conversation, why is it possible to use "Not at all"?

I agree with you. I would understand "Not at all" to mean "Absolutely not", i.e. to refuse permission.

If you reply "Not at all" to the question "Is it okay if I bring my little brother?" this could be seen as rude or offensive, because it is a very strong way of saying no, to a request that was very polite.
In this situation, "Not at all" means that under no circumstances would I accept you bringing your little brother, and I doubt that was the intention.

I think you could write "It's not at all OK"  for great emphasis upon just how not-OK it is, but not simply "Not at all" as that phrase is so frequently used in response to negative-spin questions ("Do you mind if...", "Would it bother you if...") that it could be misunderstood to mean "It's OK".  In conversation, however, of-course-it's-ok "Not at all" sounds very different from under-no-circumstances "Not at all", and your tone of voice would make absolutely clear whether permission was being granted or withheld.
